# PHP Splitting a single DateTime in several of them

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-arithmetic

Let's say I have an event that starts on 2014-05-20 09:00 and ends on 2014-05-20 17:00! What I want is to be able to split this event in two, say the break hours are 11:00 - 12:00 (which are stored as datetimes actually) and it would result into 4 datetimes:

```
2014-05-20 09:00 – 2014-05-20 11:00
2014-05-20 12:00 – 2014-05-20 17:00
```

I could have several break hours that split the event into many sub-events.

My idea is to sort the break hours datetimes and use the first break hour end time as the end start for the 1st subevent or vice versa depending when the break hour is. But there is a lot of calculation to be done here this way, isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Simpler as in, the result is going to calculate itself? I hope not because I like being paid.

Comment: At a minimum, edit your question to show sample data.  Any queries that you have tried are also welcome.

Comment: Are the dates always the same for an event? Or can they rollover onto the next day?

Comment: are break hours always going to be same?

Comment: This actually gets much more complicated than you might realize. For example, what if event A starts at 8:00 and ends at 13:00 while event B starts at 11:00 and ends at 14:00? When you try to carve event A by masking out event B, you end up losing the original end time. So your system already needs some method of imposing rules on which related events can be applied to the target event before the subevents can be derived.